# Prestashop Update cart using Webservices

Tags: php, android, web-services, prestashop

I use prestashop API web services in my android application to create a cart and modify it as needed from the user.

I have no problems with the creation of the cart, but when I add a new product the old one is removed.

```
try{
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($serverUrl, $serverApiKey, true);
$opt = array('resource' => 'carts');
$opt['id'] = $idCart;
$xml = $webService->get($opt);
$resources = $xml->children()->children()->children();
unset($xml->children()->children()->associations->cart_rows->cart_row);
$xml->children()->children()->associations->cart_rows->addChild('cart_row')->addChild('id_product', $idProduct);
$xml->children()->children()->associations->cart_rows->cart_row->addChild('quantity', $qty);
$opt = array('resource' => 'carts');
$opt['putXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$opt['id'] = $idCart; // 17
$xml = $webService->edit($opt);}
catch(PrestaShopWebserviceException $e){
// Here we are dealing with errors
$trace = $e->getTrace();if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID'; else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
else echo 'Other error'.$e->getMessage();}
```

Comment: Hey there! I removed some unnecessary text from an otherwise well-asked question. Please understand that "thanks" or "please help" are not directly related to the question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For the first time it's ok, but for the next times you call that code, with "unset($xml->children()->children()->associations->cart_rows->cart_row);" I think you remove the previous cart_row added with that line.

Comment: If i remove this line the first product added will be deleted